# Hi I am trying to saving my data in nodejs rest api but getting an error "req.status is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
router.post('/savedata',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var data={
        firstname:req.body.firstname,
        lastname:req.body.firstname,
        password:req.body.password,
        email:req.body.email,
        created:req.body.created,
        employeeid:req.body.employeeid,
        joiningdate:req.body.joiningdate,
        phone:req.body.phone,
        designation:req.body.designation,    
    };
    console.log(data);
    var _newdata = new department(data);
    console.log(_newdata);
    _newdata.save(function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
        if(err){
            req.status(500).send({message:err.message})
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result)
    });
});
```

this my code for saving data this my cmd screenshot. many thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6C23.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your code below:

```
if(err){
            req.status(500).send({message:err.message})
        }
```

**req** (request) should be replaced with **res** (response).

`res.status()` , `res.send()` , `res.end()` or any function to send response back works with res object not with req.

res.status() Sets the HTTP status for the response. It is a chainable alias of Node’s response.statusCode. See [Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status)

Answer (score 0):

replace **req** into **res** because res is the object that is response for back with response

Comment: hey thanks Ahmed can you please tell me about this error

Comment: {
    "message": "dept validation failed: joiningdate: Cast to Number failed for value \"13/05/2018\" at path \"joiningdate\", password: Path `password` is required."
}

Comment: joiningdate must to be number not string and your data object must have key with name password var data={
        password:<value>,
        joiningdate:<number>,    
    };

Comment: joining date is an number and I have written the code exactly you mentioned, and the above error is showing on postman

Comment: var app=require('express');
var router=app.Router();
var mongojs=require('mongojs');
var department=require('../models/department.js');

Comment: router.post('/savedata',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var data={
        firstname:req.body.firstname,
        lastname:req.body.firstname,
        password:req.body.password,
        email:req.body.email,

Comment: created:req.body.created,
        employeeid:req.body.employeeid,
        joiningdate:req.body.joiningdate,
        phone:req.body.phone,
        designation:req.body.designation,    
    };

Comment: console.log(data);
    var _newdata = new department(data);
    console.log(_newdata);
    _newdata.save(function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message:err.message})
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result)
    });
});

Comment: did you use body-parser middleware ??

Comment: yes in main.js var bodyparser=require('body-parser') I have used this

Comment: kindly write this console.log(req.body);  to check values in req.body

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `res` instead `req` `res.status(500).send({message:err.message})`